# jquery Datepicker triggers validation on focus out

Tags: jquery, plugins, datepicker

I have a form with several fields of which one uses the jquery datepicker plugin to let the user select a date.

I want the form to be validated only after the submit button is clicked.

jquery validate plugin is used for form validation.

```
$("#newRequestForm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules : {
                       name : {
                                 required: true,
                                 minlength: 5
                        },
        dueDateValue : {
            required: true,
            DateFormat: true
        }
    }
})
```

The user should be able to tab through the form fields without triggering the validation.

This works fine for the normal text fields in the form. However for the text field where the datepicker is applied, form validation is triggered as soon as the focus moves out of that field.
This is how the datepicker is called. The onSelect is for validating only after a date is selected.

```
$("#dueDateValue").datepicker( {
               minDate: new Date(),
               onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                       $("#newRequestForm").validate().element("#dueDateValue");
               }
});
```

The validate plugin should not validate if the user just tabs in to the duedate field and goes out without selecting a date.

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: well, i figured it myself.. Theer is a property, onfocusout, within validate itself that will let you do this..

just had to set, 

    $("#newRequestForm").validate({     debug: true,     rules : {..},
    onfocusout: true
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property, onfocusout, within validate itself that will let you do this.. just had to set, `$("#newRequestForm").validate({ debug: true, rules : {..}, onfocusout: true });`